# dispatch a custom action on redux-form when onchange select

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

Given a custom component:

```
export const RenderDropDown = (props) => {
    const {values, input, label, type, meta: {touched, error, active}} = props;

    var options = function (value, index) {
        return <Option key={index}
                       value={value} />
    };

    return(
        <div>
        <select {...input}>
            <option value="">--- Select a nationality ---</option>
            {values.map(options)}
        </select>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Wrapped in a Redux-form Field component

```
<Field name="nationality" component={RenderDropDown} values={props.nationalities}/>
```

I want that when `select` fires "onChange" event, a custom action is dispatched besides the Redux-form action (AKA @@redux-form/change)

How I can achieve this?

I tried to pass by props the function to call and set an onChange handler on `<select>` tag but this overrides the redux-form onChange.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

You need to call the redux-form `onChange` manually in your own custom `onChange` to update the redux-form value. Like so:

```
const { onChange, ... } = props;
...
<select onChange={(e) => {
    const val = e.target.value
    // whatever stuff you want to do
    onChange(val)
}} />
```

Comment: Hey @inostia thanks for your answer. I found myself the answer. looks like it was implemented already but I missed it in some way: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/releases Event callbacks! - You may now pass onChange, onBlur, onFocus, etc. props to Field...

Comment: Thanks @VicensFayos. I was using redux-form 5.x.x but have now updated to 6.5.x. So if you pass onChange directly to <Field /> does it automatically call the redux-form onChange after yours? (i.e. to update the field value in the redux-form store)